# How to use Flot charts with Flask?

Tags: python, flask, flot, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a SQLAlchemy model in Flask holding series of timestamps and values. I'd like to draw a chart using Flot charts from these data but can't find any information on how to do this.

```
class Reading(database.Model):
    __tablename__= 'Readings'
    index = database.Column('id', database.Integer, primary_key = True)
    timestamp = database.Column('Timestamp', database.DateTime)
    value = database.Column('Value', database.Float)
```

I know how to get the data in Flask app and how to use Flot charts in html but have no idea how to connect these two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to convert the timestamp to milliseconds, other then that it's quite easy to plot graphs with flot. You just need to create a list of datapoints, `[[timestamp1, value1], [timestamp2, value2], ...]` and pass it along with the render_template. Hopefully the example below can help you.

```
def request_graph_data():
   data = [[0, 3], [4, 5], [8, 1], [9, 3]]    
   return flask.render_template("graph.html",
                                 list_of_data=data)  


<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
       var d1 = {{ list_of_data }};

       var d2 = [[0, 3], [4, 8], [8, 5], [9, 13]];

       // A null signifies separate line segments
       var d3 = [[0, 12], [7, 12], null, [7, 2.5], [12, 2.5]];

       $.plot("#placeholder", [ d1, d2, d3 ]);
    });
</script>

<div class="demo-container">
        <div id="placeholder" class="demo-placeholder"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Now this make sense why there is so little information how to use Flot with Flask - it's very easy. Now I just need to figure out a way to properly format my data. Thanks.